# Trouble removing .html URL extension using .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, url

Trying to remove .html extensions from the site using .htaccess. So for example: www.mysite.com/charts.html would become www.mysite.com/charts

The following script is in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

But when the url without the .html extension is entered in the browser, it shows a 403 Forbidden error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would we have to create a conf file? Looked around and don't see a conf file anywhere in our server files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this solution elsewhere:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

sources: 
1) http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-useful-htaccess-snippets-to-have-in-your-toolbox
2) http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2007/08/19/removing-file-extension-via-htaccess/

Comment: I've tried all of the different scripts they had on that website but none seem to work and the 403 error keeps coming up.

Comment: Got it working with this script after removing a folder with the same html file name. Thanks.

Comment: Worked. Thanks!