# Remove .html extension from url using .htaccess giving 403 forbidden error in some urls

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

In my website I am using this .htaccess code to remove .html extensions from url. It works fine in some urls but it gives 403 forbidden error in some urls. I checked file permissions of these urls. Those are ok 0644.

Comment: Are they interfering with actual directories?

Comment: Without these rules, do the normal files produce a forbidden error too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble removing .html URL extension using .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676547/trouble-removing-html-url-extension-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Per [Trouble removing .html URL extension using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676547/trouble-removing-html-url-extension-using-htaccess)