# How to remove all /page.html from your URL

Tags: .htaccess, web

So I asked this question before but got none working answer, maybe I defined it in a wrong way.

My question is: How can I remove all / urls from my link.
So for example: the URL right now is: `exampledomain.com/a/dashboard.html`
But I want it to be: `exampledomain.com/` and nothing after it.
So basicly nothing after the example.com/.
Is that possible? I guess it has to be done in the .htaccess file but couldnt find a working rule.

So now it is: `exampledomain.com/a/dashboard.html`
But I want it to be: `exampledomain.com` & nothing behind that / when u go to the dashboard.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess remove all /example from website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51443879/htaccess-remove-all-example-from-website)

Comment: Yes you might use htaccess for redirection, check the following questions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676547/trouble-removing-html-url-extension-using-htaccess?rq=1
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url/5730126#5730126

More about .htaccess
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

You might also use whatever your back-end code to redirect to proper url

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below rule in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule .* / [L,R=302]
```